# Angular filter for date in HTML

Tags: angularjs, date-formatting

I am trying to filter the date using angular filter in HTML. But it is not working.

Here is my template code:

```
{{due_date | date:'MM/dd/yy'}}
```

- The input is: `{"due_date" : "2015-10-10 16:00:00.000+0000"}`
- The expected output is: `10/10/15`

What mistake am I doing?

Comment: To help the community, your post was missing the current output (what error did you get, and what did the browser display instead of the expected result?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens becouse `due_date` is a `String` instead of a `Date` object.

You can "convert" it by doing (maybe you should put this into your controller):

```
var due_date_parsed = new Date(due_date);
```

Comment: if i parse the date "2015-12-16 22:00:12.844+0000" and use {{created_date_parsed | date:'hh:mm a'}} it is showing as 05:00 PM but it should be 10:00 PM.

Answer (score 0):

parse your date like :

```
$scope.date = Date.parse(new Date());
```

in you code

```
Date.parse(jobDetails.trs_data.due_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

if string is also in proper date format like '20140313T00:00:00' then this code will work perfectly fine. In other case you will have to convert/parse the string to date type.

Comment: if i parse the date "2015-12-16 22:00:12.844+0000" and use {{created_date_parsed | date:'hh:mm a'}} it is showing as 05:00 PM but it should be 10:00 PM.